# Set active class on current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this navigation, but I can't seem to find a solution to add an .active class to the current page. Can anyone help me here?

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-ul navigation">
    <div class="menu-first">
      <li><a href="index.php"><span class="main-title">X-BIKES</span></a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-second">
        <li><a href="index.php?page=events">Events</a></li>
        <?php if (empty($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=login">Login</a></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
      <?php else: ?>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a></li>

      <li class="menu-cart">
        <a href="index.php?page=cart">Cart (<?php
          if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            echo '0';
          }else {
            echo sizeof($_SESSION['cart']);
          };
      ?>)</a>
      </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you can set active class depending on your `page` param

Comment: What do you mean by '*adding an .active class*" ? Do you want to find when a link is active ?

Comment: @Louis'LYRO'Dupont If I'm on the events page, I'd like to see the li element 'events' in a colour.

Comment: @ArtOsi What do you mean? Can you give an example please?

Comment: something like in @Jonathan answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$_GET`:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-ul navigation">
    <div class="menu-first">
      <li><a href="index.php"><span class="main-title">X-BIKES</span></a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-second">
        <li class="<?php echo $_GET['page'] == "events" ? "active" : ""; ?>" ><a href="index.php?page=events">Events</a></li>
        <?php if (empty($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $_GET['page'] == "login" ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="index.php?page=login">Login</a></li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li class="<?php echo $_GET['page'] == "register" ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
      <?php else: ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $_GET['page'] == "logout" ? "active" : ""; ?>"><a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a></li>

      <li class="menu-cart <?php echo $_GET['page'] == "cart" ? "active" : ""; ?>">
        <a href="index.php?page=cart">Cart (<?php
          if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            echo '0';
          }else {
            echo sizeof($_SESSION['cart']);
          };
      ?>)</a>
      </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And then in the CSS, you can change the link colour:

```
.navigation a {
  color: blue;
}

.navigation .active a {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: You could do it with JS as well, but you would end up with a flash of un-styled menus.

Comment: PS - I noticed you are new here, welcome!  You can accept the answer that best resolves your issue by clicking the grey checkbox on the left side of the answer.  That lets others know that you have found what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use your `page` parameter to check what link has been clicked and set the class accordingly.

For example you can write something like this at the beginning of your script:

```
var page = $_GET['page'];
```

and then later in your code

```
<a href="index.php?page=events" <?php if (page == 'events') echo 'class="active"' ?>>Events</a>
```

Hope this is the right syntax. It's been a while since I wrote my last php code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for getting the current page

and after you will compare this current page width  your link and add class .active if they are equals

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul class="menu-ul navigation">
<div class="menu-first">
<li><a href="index.php"><span class="main-title">X-BIKES</span></a>
</li>
</div>
<div class="menu-second">
<li><a <?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php?page=events' ? 
'class="active"' : '' ?> href="index.php?page=events">Events</a></li>
<?php if (empty($_SESSION['user'])): ?>
<li><a href="index.php?page=login">Login</a></li>
<li>/</li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
<li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a></li>
<li class="menu-cart">
<a  <?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php?page=cars' ? 
'class="active"' : '' ?> href="index.php?page=cart">Cart (<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
echo '0';
}else {
echo sizeof($_SESSION['cart']);
};
?>)</a>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Active menu for current page such as contact.php, about.php, we can make variable like $currentpage with asign different value for diffrent page

```
$currentPage = 'contact'; // current page is contact
```

In header section like do below

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='contact'){echo 'active';}?>" ><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='about'){echo 'active';}?>" ><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
```